# Laravel - login for auth with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My Laravel is a fresh install.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@idle');

Route::get('login', 'MainController@login');

Route::get('call', 'MainController@call')->before('auth');
```

**MainController.php**

```
class MainController extends Controller {

   public function idle() {
      return Response::json('idle');
   }

   public function login() {
      $user = array(
         'username' => Input::get('username'),
         'password' => Input::get('password')
      );

      if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
         return Redirect::intended();
      } else {
         return Redirect::route('login');
      }
   }

   public function call() {
      $users = User::all();
      return $users;
   }

}
```

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Requesting:

`http://l0calhost/survey/public/login`

```
    InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
```

Why does it say it is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you added an AUTH filter

```
Route::get('call', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'MainController@call'));
```

Laravel will assume you have a route

```
Route::get('login', ...);
```

You will find something like this in your `filters.php` file and you can change it to whatever is best to you:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

You'll have to name your route too:

```
Route::get('login', array('as' = 'login', 'use' => 'MainController@login'));
```

Comment: Thanks :D I just figured it out. What is the function `guest()`? Can you post a link to a best practice auth login function? But I am still unsure: Do I need `Route::get('login')` or where should my login with `attempt()` etc. take place? Thanks!

Comment: ´Auth::guest()´ checks if the user is a guest, if the user is currently logged in, it will return false, as he/she is not a a guest.

Comment: No I meant `Redirect::guest`, but I found it saves the current request to be called later again.

Comment: Oh! It will redirect as always, but will store the current URL so after a login you can Redirect::intended() the user to the url he was trying to reach.

Comment: Thank you!! I LOVE LARAVEL :D

Comment: Can you please see my edit in the question? Although I have setup everything correct now, it says `InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.`

Comment: It is trying to find a route by its name, not uri. Just edited.